# how to download linkedin (save as pdf option) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Image what i want to download.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpf1f.png)

Image is of LinkedIn profile page of my friend
i want to click on that save-as-pdf option for many users.

can that be downloaded using python code? for different users?
or can it be downloaded using any other language?

Comment: There may be something you can use on the [LinkedIn Developer Network](https://developer.linkedin.com/). If not, you need a script that will determine the location of the PDF for a given user and download it. You might want to try copying the URL of the PDF and examining it for variables, located after the `?` (I saw id, locale, authType, authToken, pdfFileName, and a few other options). If you can programmatically change these options and download from the resulting URL, your solution might work.

Comment: till now, i tried autohotkey to automate clicking for me (that saves pdf programmatically) but with time the ID of element keeps changing in linkedin webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can automate this with python that works for every profile, so you dont have to worry about ids changing

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

login = "Email address goes here"
password = "Type your password here"

#start browser session 
chromedriver = "/home/romtein/chromedriver" #change this to your selenium driver
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

#open linkedin in automated browser
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
time.sleep(1)

#logs you into Linkedin
driver.find_element_by_id("login-email").send_keys(str(login))
password = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password").send_keys(str(password))
driver.find_element_by_id("login-submit").click()
print("successfully logged in")

#navigates to your connections
time.sleep(1)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/")
time.sleep(1)

#opens a new tab of your top contact
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').perform()
contact_page_open = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__name").click()
time.sleep(2)

#switch to new tab
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(1)
# ActionChains(driver).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

#click the "more" button
driver.find_element_by_class_name("pv-s-profile-actions__overflow").click()
time.sleep(1)

#saves profile to pdf 
driver.find_element_by_class_name("pv-s-profile-actions pv-s-profile-actions--save-to-pdf").click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Let me know if you have any questions