# how to download LinkedIn Resume in 2022 (save as pdf option) for give profile using python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

What I want to do is save the resume provided by LinkedIn (save as pdf option) as in this figure.[image] I use Google Chrome as my browser. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928227/how-to-download-linkedin-save-as-pdf-option-using-python). but I failed to reproduce the answer for the 2022 LinkedIn UI version. How to reproduce this answer for 2022?

This is what I already Tried.

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

login = "##############"
password = "############"

class Linkedin:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username=username
        self.password=password

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.bot=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

    def login(self):
            bot=self.bot
            bot.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
            time.sleep(3)
            email=bot.find_element(By.ID,"username")
            email.send_keys(self.username)
            password=bot.find_element(By.ID,"password")
            password.send_keys(self.password)
            time.sleep(3)
            password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

load=Linkedin(login,password)
load.login()
print("Successfully logged in")

#navigates to your profile
time.sleep(1)
load.bot.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/isuru-alagiyawanna-536881121/")
time.sleep(1)

#clicks on the "more" button on Linkedin
load.bot.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"pv-top-card-section__inline-overflow-button").click()
```

This returns the **NoSuchElementException** Error.

Comment: you need to share some code and your approach

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? What browser do you use? What URL do you want to download? Put all details in question, not in comments.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I just updated my question. please support on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to tried, it worked well

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()
tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.linkedin.com/in/isuru-alagiyawanna-536881121/")
#elem = tab.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="More"]').click()
#tab.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@aria-hidden="false"]//span[text()="Save to PDF"]').click()
tab.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@aria-hidden="true"]//span[text()="Save to PDF"]').click()
```

Comment: there is another development tool associated with this lib, that may be helpful for you.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium